# How do I combine various independent validations in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I apologize in advance for not being quite sure how to word this question in the title.

I'm new to Laravel and am developing in Laravel 6. I am trying to incorporate both client-side and server-side validations in my app, which is basically a CRUD. I will gather some information from a user via forms, validate them, and then store the record in MySQL. I think I understand how to do the server-side validations but I'm struggling with the client-side. I had a superficial knowledge of jQuery several years ago and have forgotten almost all of it, which probably accounts for my current confusion.

I've knocked together a prototype input form in a Laravel view. I'm trying to add client-side validations and have chosen jQuery validations, mostly because it's the one I know a little bit from years ago. (I could definitely be talked into doing it another way if someone can suggest a better approach.) The form in my prototype has two simple text fields, a date field, a time field, and a checkbox.

I'm using a jQuery plugin to display the date- and time-pickers. Here is [the documentation for that plugin](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/). I put the javascript in a file called sandbox.js. The rest of the code is in this view, sandbox.blade.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="/lib/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid bg">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<h1>Sleep Form</h1>
<form id="registration-form">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name" class="col-4 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-8">
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="sleepDate" class="col-4 col-form-label">Sleep Date</label>
    <div class="col-2">
      <input type="text" id="sleepDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Click to choose date">   
    </div>   
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="sleepTime" class="col-4 col-form-label">Sleep Time</label>
  <div class="col-2">
    <input type="text" id="sleepTime" class="form-control" placeholder="Click to choose time">   
  </div>   
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="minutesAerobic" class="col-4 col-form-label">Minutes of aerobic exercise you took on this day</label>
    <div class="col-8">
      <input type="text" id="minutesAerobic" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>       
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="sunlight">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="sunlight">
      I got at least two hours of sunlight on this day
    </label>
  </div> 
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>  -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2.0.0-rc.3"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/sandbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the sandbox.js file contains only the code to display the datepicker and the timepicker, both display just fine. Here's what the sandbox.js file looks like then:

```
$('#sleepDate').datetimepicker({
timepicker: false,
datepicker: true,
format: 'Y-m-d',
defaultDate: new Date(),
weeks: false
})

$('#sleepTime').datetimepicker({
timepicker: true,
datepicker: false,
format: 'H:i',
hours12: false,
step: 15
})
```

Now I am trying to add validations for the text field. I also want to show any error messages on the line below the text field. Here is what my amended code looks like:

```
$('#sleepDate').datetimepicker({
timepicker: false,
datepicker: true,
format: 'Y-m-d',
defaultDate: new Date(),
weeks: false
})

$('#sleepTime').datetimepicker({
timepicker: true,
datepicker: false,
format: 'H:i',
hours12: false,
step: 15
})
$("#registration-form").validate({
rules: {
    name: {
        required: true
    },
    minutesAerobic: {
        required: true
    }
},
messages: {
    name: {
        required: '[JQV] Please supply your name'
    },
    minutesAerobic: {
        required: '[JQV] Please enter the number of minutes of aerobic exercise you did during this day'
    }       
  }
})

$.validator.setDefaults({
errorClass: 'help-block',
highlight: function(element) {
    $(element)
        .closest('.form-control')
        .addClass('has-error');
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element)
        .closest('.form-control')
        .removeClass('has-error');
}
})
```

When I try to test this code, I see no sign of the new edits working but the date and time still display just fine so at least I haven't broken that. I get no error message of any kind when I leave all the fields untouched and just click Submit. I can't tell if my form validation of registration-form is doing anything at all. I'm not sure if it is finding errors but is unable to display them or if it is not even seeing the errors because it isn't coded properly. I'm also rather uneasy about the four separate blocks of code all just sitting together in the sandbox.js file; I wonder if each block (except the last one) should end with a semicolon and if all 4 blocks should be surrounded by

```
$(function() {
});
```

I've tried it both ways but the behaviour of the code doesn't change; it seems to be broken both ways.

I've spent hours looking for an example that combines regular jQuery validate stuff with this date/timepicker examples that use this plugin but haven't seen anything like that so I'm really unclear about the proper structure of sandbox.js.

I would also welcome advice on how to tell if the validation of registration-form is actually working. I'm writing my code in VSCode and knowing how to debug Laravel in VSCode would be really helpful but I'm quite prepared to settle for more basic techniques of telling what code is actually executing.

If anyone can point me to an actual example of a Laravel view doing client-side editing of a "create" form, I think that would be REALLY helpful, especially if it used Bootstrap4 and jQuery. I'm very new to the Laravel world and I just don't know where I could look for such a thing.

Comment: Since you're talking entirely about client-side validation, Laravel is not relevant to your question. Do keep in mind that server-side is where the important validation happens, so client-side validation should be minimal if you want to avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: @miken32 - Yes, I suppose you're right about Laravel not being relevant. I mentioned Laravel on the off-chance that it made any difference whatsoever in how I should approach things. I'm still confused about repeating myself though. Shouldn't I do every possible validation on the server side, in case the user has Javascript turned off, and then do the exact same validations on the client-side in case the user has left Javascript on?

Comment: Server-side is always done and is what protects your data integrity. Client side is only there if you want things to look a bit prettier for the user.

Comment: [A name attribute is mandatary for this plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations) and any input without a name attribute is going to be ignored.  You should at least fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery validation looks for `name` attribute in an `input` try adding the `name` attribute and then use the name attribute as properties in `rules` and `messages`.

You can refer jQuery Validation documentation from [here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Comment: Thanks, Ronak, but I already had that; it doesn't answer my questions though. I'm not sure how to mix and match regular jQuery validations with the parameters for this datepicker/timepicker plugin or how to determine if they're even executing. That's my biggest concern. Nothing SEEMS to be happening but maybe I just haven't allowed it to show me the errors. I should get Required errors on the two text fields but I'm not. Can you see why?

Comment: @Henry, then edit your question as such.  [A `name` attribute is mandatary for this plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations) and any input without a `name` attribute is going to be ignored.